# Apply built-in extension buttons to custom toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i am looking for a way to display forge-viewer buildin extension buttons in another toolbar.
E.g. `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` or `Autodesk.LayerManager`.

I found a way to to add the control-button to the custom toolbar by asking for the control-id in `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup.Event.CONTROL_ADDED` event, remove the control from the original toolbar and add it to anthoer.
But when i do this, some functions from the control-button are no longer available.

E.g. when i load the `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` in another toolbar, i am able to use it as usual. But after switching viewables, the contorl-button stays activated for ever. The panel toggels after pressing the button, but the button stays activated.

I also tried to pass options to this method, but this does not affect anything:

```js
viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DocumentBrowser",{parentControl:"custom-toolbar"})
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the built-in viewer extensions do not provide any configuration as to which toolbar their buttons should be added to. Moreover, the extensions will often reference the main toolbar (`this.viewer.toolbar`) throughout their code, so even if you moved their buttons into another toolbar manually, you would very likely start running into all sorts of strange behaviors.

I believe the safest approach would be to create new toolbar buttons entirely, and try and reuse as much of the extension's functionality as possible. For example, in case of the `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` extension, you could try and subclass the `DocumentBrowser` class, and override the `UiController` object it uses internally to add the toolbar UI. Of course, this will require more or less effort depending on how the extension is implemented.